# Why does HttpWebRequest.GetResponse() fail in an ASP.NET page under IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, https

I built a set of API's for one of our developers to consume in our web application. I did this in a .NET 4.0 class library project and wrote integration tests to ensure the API integrated with the backend service correctly. In the integration tests (a unit test project), as well as a console application, the API's work correctly and return all the expected results. However, when we execute the same API's from a ASP.NET web page that is running under IIS, the API fails at the following line of code:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebRequest)request.GetResponse())
```

The failure is a `WebException` with a status of `SendFailure` and a socket error of `ConnectionReset  (10054)` in the inner exception. The error is `The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send`. This is using HTTPS, as well (hence the X509).

I already know that this is actually when the request is made, but I'm trying to pin-point what is different about an IIS environment that would prevent the stream from being able to write bytes over the network. I know that this is actually the web service server closing the connection before we get a chance to send our data, but I want to urge, again, that this same API works fine under a integration or unit test, or console application all day long.

I have already exhausted as many articles and posts on the internet that are related that I could find, including extensive Msdn documentation such as checking things related to the certificate, modifying HTTP headers service point properties. I'm truly at a loss because the code is not complicated, I've written web request code too many times to count, but here it is:

```
private string ExecuteServiceMessages(Uri serviceUrl, X509Certificate clientCertificate, string requestBody)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);

    request.ClientCertificates.Add(clientCertificate);
    request.Date = DateTime.Now;
    request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    request.ContentType = MediaTypeNames.Text.Xml;
    request.UserAgent = "******";
    request.KeepAlive = false;

    using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream))
    {
        writer.Write(requestBody);
        writer.Close();
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        string data = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();

        return data;
    }
}
```

The certificate is being loaded in by `X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile`, where our certificate for testing is just in a directory of the website. We're not pulling it directly from the certificate store (unless we don't fully understand how certificates work when loaded from a file).

Comment: Chances are that there is something wrong with getting cert - i.e. IIS runs under account that does not have access to store where cert is or cert is not in MyComputer, but instead in MY for your user's account.

Comment: We're actually loading the certificate from the file system using `X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile`. Does that scenario you suggested still apply?

Comment: Should be fine. I'd try to call my own test location and see if certificate is indeed reaches the other side... If you have control of service you call try to turn off "client certificates" and see anything else wrong (also I doubt).

Comment: Unfortunately we don't control the service. However, I did find that I was able to get it to work by changing the identity account of the application pool from Network Service to Local System. I know Local System has full control, so is there some permission we need to setup under a special account for our AppPools that we are missing?

Comment: I don't know - I'd use "process explorer" to see if there is any interesting request for resources/files failing... But first I'd check code for "eat all exceptions" `try/catch` cases - maybe there some more obvious issue where you are not able to load cert. You can also try to add full control to network service on folder where cert is located...

Comment: Will do all that first thing in the morning and let you know the results. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a delay of any kind before you get the error (e.g. something that might indicate a timeout is occuring)?

A lot happens when the framework tries to validate that certificate.  One of the things it may do (depending on the X509 policy you're using) is check the Certificate Revocation List, which requires a connection to the internet.  This has bitten us a couple times when we tried to run the code on a server that is in an environment with limited internet access-- it spins for exactly 60 seconds then returns the error you are seeing (not very helpful).  If this is it, you can change your CRL policy to offline, or edit your hosts file and override DNS so that the CRL check is performed using the loopback address-- it'll fail but at least you won't get a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You may be connecting internet through a proxy check your IE lan settings.
from c# you need to add proxy settings

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.CreateHttp(url);
                    WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("http://127.0.0.1:8888", true);
                    proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("ID", "pwd", "Domain");
                    request.Proxy = proxy;
                    request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

                    request.Timeout = 1000 * 60 * 5;
                    request.Method = method;
```

return request.GetResponse();